# How to pass variable from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried to pass a value from my controller to a view but it has not worked.

I am passing the value from a view to a controller using an Ajax script which works perfectly fine. Then what I want to do is to pass that value to the Index controller and show it in the View for the Index.

Here is my Controller :

```
    static string global;
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        TempData["var"] = id;
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public object functon(string data)
    {
        return Index(data);
    }
```

here is my View :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<input class="form-group" id="input"/>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="send">Send</button>

@if ((string)TempData["var"] == null)
{
    <span>Check</span>
}
else
{
    <h1>@TempData["var"].ToString()</h1>
}

@* SCRIPT *@
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#send").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Acceptvalue/functon",
                    data: '{data: "' + $("#input").val() + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use ViewModels:

```
public virtual ActionResult Method()
    {
        MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
        vm.Name = "MyName";
        return View(MVC.Controller.Views.MyView, vm); //also works with partial views
    }
```

And then in my view:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel

<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

Comment: Is there an error? or does the model not have a value?

Comment: I am getting the value in the view when I debug. but unable to show it to my view page

Comment: Can you share your version of the view and controller so I can help further?

Answer (score -1):

Use ViewBag and fill it in your controller:

```
ViewBag.var = id
```

and then access it in view:

```
@if(Viewbag.var == null)
```

Also, edit your function() with:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = data });
```

Comment: Are you sure you get a value for "string id" in Index()?

Comment: Also, try to edit your function() with: return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = data });

Comment: `@if (ViewBag.var == null)
{

}
else
{
    <h1>@ViewBag.var</h1>
}` Now i am getting value to the View but unable to print it to browser using this h1 tag !

Comment: Is there any error or the <h1> isn't even rendered?

Comment: `public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            ViewBag.var = id;
            return View();
        }` I think when I click the button it loads the entire page again like postback. that is the reason i am unable to see the result. Because ViewBage gets over written when page loads.

Comment: If you want to return only one value without entire page postback, you need to use Ajax success: function () and set <h1> value via Javascript.